# Render html content in layout based on value defined in consuming page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way in which I can define a value or section in an MVC page that is consumed by the Layout file to display optional content in the layout file.

_Layout.cshtml

```
@if (someValueToCheck)
{
    //HTML content that will render on every page requiring this content
}
```

Somepage.cshtml

```
@{
   // set someValueToCheck to notify the Layout to render content
}
```

Comment: WHat do you mean by _then some contant that gets rendered along with it_ (and I assume that is _content_?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke a number of HTML tags constructed in a way that resembles a container.

Comment: I don't always want to utilise that container and have it rendered on every page, only some that inherit from the layout file. Otherwise I could have done this easily. but the problem is with it being optional and I really don't want to create an almost I dentical layout file and inherit from that instead when needed.

Comment: But that is exactly what `RenderSection()` does (and you can have as many as you want). So long as you add the `required:false` argument, it means that its optional, and will only be displayed if the view contains a `@section mySection { ... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes but considering that some of the HTML tags that form a container that goes within that section, I want to avoid re-defining that container over and over again.

Comment: You need to give us an example of what you trying to render

Comment: @StephenMuecke Check out my answer hopefully that will clarify what I am after, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That is what a `RenderSection` does you need to read `RenderSection` in more details that is the answer to your question, and please try to provide more detail in your questions. you can make 2 RenderSection if you need

Comment: Downvoted.  This question makes no sense, and your example does not help.  You should include what you want it to look like both ways.  Maybe the method [IsSectionDefined (existed since MVC3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage.issectiondefined?view=aspnetcore-2.1) can help.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't see how this question can make anymore sense, you are right IsSectionDefined allows me to do what I want to do, thanks for the suggesstion and feedback on the downvote reason!

Answer (score 1):

I think this can't be done and the closest is defining an almost identical layout file, but that is still ugly, therefore the below may be better:

**_Layout2.cshtml**

```
@RenderPage("_Layout")

<div class="common-body-container">
    <div class="common-body-container-header">
        <div class="common-body-container-page-title">blah blah!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="common-body-container-contents">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

This way I am not redifining an almost identical layout file and also not repeating the HTML tags forming the container on evey page.

**Edit:** Thanks to @ErikPhilips [IsSectionDefined(string section)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage.issectiondefined?view=aspnetcore-2.1) Does the trick, it will render optional content from within the layout only when a section is defined within the content page:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("commonBodyContainer")){
    <div class="common-body-container">
       <div class="common-body-container-header">
           <div class="common-body-container-page-title">blah blah!</div>
       </div>
       <div class="common-body-container-contents">
           @RenderSection(commonBodyContainer)
       </div>
    </div>    
} else {
    @RenderBody()
}
```

Comment: Your example Layout file does not render a body at all if the section is not defined??

Answer (score 0):

Sections are typically used to define content in a page, and displayed in a Layout.  So if that's what you're *actually* trying to accomplish then it would look like:

_Layout.cshtml

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("optionalSection")){
  <div class="optional-content">
       @RenderSection(commonBodyContainer)
  </div>    
} 

@RenderBody()
```

renderOptionalContent.cshtml

```
@section optionalSection 
{ 
  <div>Content for opional-content</div>
}
```

If you don't need to render content passed from the view to the layout, I prefer to create a strongly typed, descriptive method to do the logic and store the value in the ViewData:

```
internal static class WebViewPageExtensions
{
    const string ViewDataContentBlahKey = "ContentBlahKey";

    public static void SetShowContentBlah(this WebViewPage instance
       ,bool value)
    {
      instance.ViewData[ViewDataContentBlahKey] = value;
    }

    public static void GetShowContentBlah(this WebViewPage instance)
    {
      // if it's not set to false, it will be null
      var result = instance.ViewData[ViewDataContentBlahKey] as bool?;
      return result.HasValue && result.Value;
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@if(GetShowContentBlah())){
  <div class="optional-content">
    My Optional Content
  </div>    
}
```

renderOptionalContent.cshtml

```
@{ SetShowContentBlah(true); }
```